# Как сделать обязательным заполнение many to many поля в doctrine orm в Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-orm

В документации описан: `* @Assert\NotBlank()`, он проверяет пустое ли поле и выдает ошибку, если оно пустое. Но этот метод, по моему мнению (потому что с ManyToMany не получается), работает только с OneToOne и ManyToOne. С ManyToMany проверка вообще не срабатывает и поле пропускается даже пустым. Как решить?

**UPDATE:**
Поскольку проблема была **именно при генерации урла в скрипте и его сохранении**, то я просто перенес генерацию в JQUery: Заголовку и slug добавил:

```html
->add('title', null, [
  'required' => true,
  'attr' => [
    'data-type' => 'toTranslate'
  ]
])
->add('slug', null, [
  'required' => true,
  'attr' => [
    'data-type' => 'urlType'
  ]
])
```

и сам js (JQuery):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function toTranslit(text) {
        var result = text.replace(/([а-яё])|([\s_-])|([^a-z\d])/gi,
            function (all, ch, space, words, i) {
                if (space || words) {
                    return space ? '-' : '';
                }
                var code = ch.charCodeAt(0),
                    next = text.charAt(i + 1),
                    index = code == 1025 || code == 1105 ? 0 :
                        code > 1071 ? code - 1071 : code - 1039,
                    t = ['yo', 'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'zh',
                        'z', 'i', 'y', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
                        'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'h', 'c', 'ch', 'sh',
                        'shch', '', 'y', '', 'e', 'yu', 'ya'
                    ],
                    next = next && next.toUpperCase() === next ? 1 : 0;
                return ch.toUpperCase() === ch ? next ? t[index].toUpperCase() :
                    t[index].substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
                    t[index].substring(1) : t[index];
            }
        );
        return result.toLowerCase();
    }
    $("[data-type=toTranslate]").on("change", function () {
        var $title =  $("[data-type=toTranslate]").val();
        var $slug = toTranslit($title);
        $("[data-type=urlType]").val($slug);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Документация доктрины говорит о том что подобную валидацию вы можете делать в  хуках. Например [вот так это описано у них в cookbook](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/validation-of-entities.html)
Вам попросту в одном из хуков, например preFlush, нужно проверить не пустая ли у вас коллекция в соответствующем поле. Так же не забывайте что у доктрины есть такие понятия как `Owning side` и `Inverse Side` и чем это грозит. [Вот чуть чуть об этом из документации Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#setting-information-from-the-inverse-side) ну и само собой полезно будет прочитать чтоб понять о чем речь в [самой документации Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#association-updates-owning-side-and-inverse-side) . Понимание этого действительно не даст вам запутаться.

Что касаемо `@Assert\NotBlank()` и прочих аннотаций, это относится к компоненту [Validation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html)

Вы же ошибочно предполагаете что это относится к доктрине потому что создаете/сохраняете/редактируете свою модель через формы и не знаете что валидацую вызывает именно `handleRequest(submit)` метод.

Представьте что вы захотите сохранить модель не через форму и сформируйте туда данные которые не должны пройти валидацию, модель без проблем сохранится в базе данных (я не беру во внимание ограничение именно базы данных, unique например) и для того чтоб у вас отработала валидация  вам нужно руками будет взять сервис валидатора и произвести валидирование данных, вот например как [показано здесь](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#the-basics-of-validation).

Comment: Спасибо. Поскольку **проблема была именно при автоматической генерации урлов при вставке в скрипте** (взято из сонатовских новостей), то я решил проблему просто переносом генерации в js

Comment: Точнее: генерация происходила после проверки на уникальность. Почему-то сами создатели сонаты это не пофиксили. В новостях точно такая же проблема. Там, вроде, не проверяются урлы новостей на уникальность. И если добавить две новости с одним урлом, то фалатьная ошибка будет.

Comment: @zalex отжал "правильный ответ" ))

Answer (score 0):

Этот метод к доктрине вообще никакого отношения не имеет, вам стоит ознакомится полностью с документацией и выяснить в какой момент времени что происходит и сразу 90% вопросов отпадет

Comment: Как бы Assert'ы имеют прямое отношение к доктрине, т.к. указывают параметры ввода/вывода. @Assert\NotBlank() - указывает, что при отсутствии значения (при вставке!) выдается ошибка. И в скобках можно указать текст ошибку. Можно же было нормальный ответ дать, а не белеберду писать)

Comment: @Gjnext, доктрина это вот этот пакет https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/orm, та аннотация из этого пакета https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/validator и они вообще не связаны и на разных уровнях и в разных котрекстах используются

Comment: Эти поля валидируются в сущности доктрины. https://symfony.ru/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html Как они могут быть не связаны? Поправочка: не ассерты, а Constraints. Assert'ы это алиасы по сути.

Как пример: @ORM\Column(type="string")
                   * @Assert\NotBlank()
создаст varchar поле и будет выдавать ошибку, если оно пустое при вставке

Comment: Блин, все. Прости :) Да, там же Симфонии namespace. Ну хорошо, это не элемент доктрины. Это параметр формы симфонии. Как тогда вешать ошибку на пустое поле в форме симфонии?

Comment: @Gjnext, никак, точнее перед persist явно проверять что не пусто или еще в какой либо момент времени и это зависит от выбранной архетектуры и задачи, которую  решаешь

Comment: @Gjnext, по сути в энтити в любой момент времени не должны находится невалидные данные