# Как реализуется предпроверка поля при добавлении нового этомента в Sonat'e? Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, doctrine-orm

Существует проблема: есть текстовое поле в БД, туда сохраняется значение ссылки на данную новость, которое, если ссылка не задана пользователем, генерируется самостоятельно (при сохранении и добавлении).

Поле должно быть уникальным, что и прописано как:  `* @UniqueEntity(fields={"slug"})`.

Т.е. при добавлении новой записи Symfony пропустит текст в этом поле, даже если он уже есть в БД.
Но при редактировании этой записи будет выдана ошибка: `Данная запись уже существует`.

Как запустить проверку на уникальность при создании записи?

Answer (score 0):

Для вашей задачи подойдёт [FormEvent](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) и не много JS. Ивенты который вам можно использовать FormEvents::SUBMIT. С помощью js вам нужно будет отлвавить событие заполнения поля формы которую вы хотите валидировать и отправлять форму.

Comment: А при чем тут js вообще? Тут вопрос уже в возможностях сонаты стандартных. Почему-то не работает уже готовый вариант проверки поля на уникальность. И работает от хорошо, только срабатывает этот метод не при вставке, а при редактировании данных.

Comment: Плохо вчитался в вопрос , подумал что проблема в другому. А при создании новой записи отправляется случайно не  коллекция данных ? Вы обратили внимание что при установки этого ограничения нужно прописывать 2 аннотации ?

Comment: Нет, я же про простое поле говорю, а не про связку ManyToMany. Я описал решение тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1090297/